# Sent Bitcore (BTX) to my Bitcoin Core wallet (a bitcoin wallet) - anyway to recover the BTX?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

Topic says it all. For some reason I thought the Bitcoin Core wallet was for holding Bitcore Coin (BTX) but obviously that isn’t the case! I sent Bitcore (BTX) coins to that wallet last night and obviously isn’t being recognized in the wallet.

Does anyone know if it is possible to recover the BTX from the Bitcoin Core wallet? The Wallet doesn’t think I received anything so not sure I can recover private keys from it that represent the BTX coins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Private keys are independent of actually receiving any coins. You can get the private keys from your wallet by using the `dumpprivkey` or `dumpwallet` commands.

Alternatively, because Bitcore's wallet is based on Bitcoin Core, you can just copy and paste your Bitcoin Core wallet.dat file into the Bitcore wallet's datadir, replacing it's wallet.dat file (assuming that you are using bitcore's fork of Bitcoin Core).

Comment: That is awesome to know. That gives me hope. Thanks!

Comment: Holy cow, this worked! It was just a matter of dumping the private key from Bitcoin Core and importing it into the BitCore (BTX) Coin wallet. It worked like a charm. I was so sure it wasn't going to work. Thank you!